# Conditionally returning the previous or next matching result outside of a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Consider the following table and Data:

```
CREATE TABLE Visits
(
    PersonID INT,
    VisitID INT,
    VisitDate DATETIME,
    VisitNumber INT,
    SomethingHappened BIT
)


INSERT INTO Visits
VALUES
(1,1,'2017-07-03',1,1),
(1,2,'2017-07-04',2,1),
(1,3,'2017-07-05',3,1),
(1,4,'2017-07-09',4,1),
(2,5,'2017-07-03',1,1),
(2,6,'2017-07-04',2,0),
(2,7,'2017-07-05',3,0),
(2,8,'2017-07-09',4,1),
(2,9,'2017-07-10',5,1),
(2,10,'2017-07-11',6,1),
(3,11,'2017-07-02',1,1),
(3,12,'2017-07-03',2,1),
(3,13,'2017-07-08',3,1),
(3,14,'2017-07-09',4,1),
(3,15,'2017-07-10',2,1),
(3,16,'2017-07-11',3,0),
(3,17,'2017-07-15',4,1)
```

I want to know, between a given date range, when "Something Happened" happened on concurrent days.

I have this as follows:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2017-07-04'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2017-07-09'

SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT      *,
                        CASE
                            WHEN LAG(VisitNumber) OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, VisitNumber) = VisitNumber - 1
                            THEN 1
                            WHEN LEAD(VisitNumber) OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, VisitNumber) =VisitNumber + 1
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS ConccurentSomethingHappened
            FROM        Visits
            WHERE       SomethingHappened = 1 AND
                        VisitDate >= @StartDate AND VisitDate <= @EndDate
        )a
WHERE ConccurentSomethingHappened = 1
ORDER BY    PersonID,
            VisitNumber
```

However, there is an issue with the query above in that a visit that is on the last day of the selected range (9th July in this example) may have "Something happened" but also "something happened" may have occurred on the next visit so won't be picked up by the query.

I want to get all the visits where SomethingHappened has happened concurrently (on two or more visits) PLUS, if something happened has happened on the first or last visits in the given criteria and SomethingHappened has also happened in the visit before or the visit after, display that too.

For the data here I would expect the results to be

```
PersonID VisitID  VisitDate             VisitNumber
1           2   2017-07-04 00:00:00.000      2
1           3   2017-07-05 00:00:00.000      3
1           4   2017-07-09 00:00:00.000      4
2           8   2017-07-09 00:00:00.000      4
2           9   2017-07-10 00:00:00.000      5
3           13  2017-07-08 00:00:00.000      3
3           14  2017-07-09 00:00:00.000      4
```

Note that visit ID 9 is showing up even though it is out of the date range, this is because visit ID 8 is within the date range and something happened in both.

In my current query, visitID 8 is excluded

Can anyone suggest how I would get the requested behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to crack this.

The creation of the following function will show those visits that are outside of the given date range but need to be included in the final result as they are part of a single pair of "SomethingHappeneds"

```
CREATE FUNCTION OverFlowedSomethingHappeneds
(
    @PersonID INT,
    @StartDate DATE,
    @EndDate DATE
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

    SELECT  PersonID,
            VisitID,
            VisitDate,
            VisitNumber,
            SomethingHappened
    FROM    (
                SELECT  *,
                        CASE
                            WHEN VisitNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 VisitNumber FROM Visits WHERE VisitDate < @StartDate AND PersonID = @PersonID ORDER BY VisitNumber DESC) AND -- previous visit to the StartDate
                                                LEAD(SomethingHappened) OVER (ORDER BY VisitNumber) =1 AND --something happened on the next visit...
                                                LEAD(SomethingHappened,2) OVER (ORDER BY VisitNumber) =0 --..but not the visit after that
                            THEN 1
                            WHEN VisitNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 VisitNumber FROM Visits WHERE VisitDate > @EndDate AND PersonID = @PersonID) AND --next visit after EndDate
                                                LAG(SomethingHappened) OVER (ORDER BY VisitNumber) =1 AND --something happened on the previous visit...
                                                LAG(SomethingHappened,2) OVER (ORDER BY VisitNumber) =0 --..but not the visit before that                               
                            THEN 1
                        END AS overflow
                FROM    Visits
                WHERE   PersonID = @PersonID
            ) a
    WHERE   overflow = 1
```

Then using an `OUTER APPLY` in the final query

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #result
SELECT      v.PersonID,
            v.VisitID,
            v.VisitDate,
            v.VisitNumber,
            v.SomethingHappened,
            o.PersonID AS PersonID2,
            o.VisitID AS VisitID2,
            o.VisitDate AS VisitDate2,
            o.VisitNumber AS VisitNumber2,
            o.SomethingHappened AS SomethingHappened2
INTO        #result
FROM        (
                SELECT *,
                      (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN LAG(VisitNumber) OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, VisitNumber) = VisitNumber - 1
                            THEN 1
                            WHEN LEAD(VisitNumber) OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, VisitNumber) = VisitNumber + 1
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END
                       ) AS ConccurentSomethingHappened
                  FROM Visits
                  WHERE SomethingHappened = 1 
             ) v
            OUTER APPLY OverFlowedSomethingHappeneds(PersonID,@StartDate,@EndDate) o
WHERE       ConccurentSomethingHappened = 1 AND
            v.VisitDate >= @StartDate AND v.VisitDate <= @EndDate
ORDER BY    PersonID,
            VisitNumber

SELECT  PersonID,
        VisitID,
        VisitDate,
        VisitNumber,
        SomethingHappened
FROM    #result
UNION
SELECT  PersonID2,
        VisitID2,
        VisitDate2,
        VisitNumber2,
        SomethingHappened2
FROM    #result
WHERE   PersonID2 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move the `where` clause to the outer query:

```
SELECT  v.*
FROM (SELECT v.*,
              (CASE WHEN LAG(VisitNumber) OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, VisitNumber) = VisitNumber - 1
                    THEN 1
                    WHEN LEAD(VisitNumber) OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, VisitNumber) = VisitNumber + 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
               END) AS ConccurentSomethingHappened
      FROM Visits
      WHERE SomethingHappened = 1 
     ) v
WHERE ConccurentSomethingHappened = 1 AND
      VisitDate >= @StartDate AND VisitDate <= @EndDate
ORDER BY PersonID, VisitNumber;
```

However, given your problem, why not just use a `JOIN`:

```
select v.*
from visits v join
     visits v2
     on v.personId = v2.personId and v.VisitNumber = v2.VisitNumber - 1
where v.SomethingHappened = 1 and v2.SomethingHappened = 1 and
      ( (v.VisitDate >= @StartDate AND v.VisitDate <= @EndDate) or
        (v2.VisitDate >= @StartDate AND v2.VisitDate <= @EndDate) );
```

With the right indexes, the `join` could be faster than the window functions.

Comment: Hi Thanks, for your suggestion.
These show up visit 8 but I also want visit 9 to show up as it is the second in the "something happened" pair

Comment: also, there is an orphaned "or" at the end of your second query causing a syntax error ;)
It's too short of an edit for SO to allow me change it